# How do I find population mean μ for a value that has uncertainty

Tags: variance, mean, population, uncertainty

I have a value *x = 60 ± 5.5*, and I want to find the population mean μ_x (mean of x), and the population variance of x. How can I do do this?

Sorry for the noob question, but I've spent 3 hours trying to get a concrete answer for this. I can elaborate if any detail is missing/needed for answering this question.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Something is missing. Consider this: If you know $P(54.5 < X < 65.6) = 0.95$ Then for a _normal_ distribution, $1.96\sigma = 5.5,$ making $\sigma = 2.80.$ In R, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF, code `diff(pnorm(c(54.5,65.5), 60, 2.8))` returns $0.950503.$

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found an answer. μ_x = 60, and variance = 5.5.

Source: solution for the question in which I needed to find these.

Comment: Your solution either gives the wrong answer, badly abuses terminology, or is quoted out of context. I recommend discussing this question further.

Comment: In $60 \pm 5.5$ the $5.5$ is unlikely to be the variance

Comment: Perhaps more likely, 5.5 is about twice $\sigma.$